# Angular Flex Layout,Static API,Vertical or Horizontal space-around with none alignment is not working

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

Why space around alignment is not working [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7aewww?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)?

The same result for space-between.
What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't give height to your div and have set the height of two subdivs to 100%, there is no place for a space!

Check out [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rderze)

Answer (score 1):

Try this for horizontal space:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around none" >
   <div fxFlex="40%" class="green-color">
     item1
   </div>
   <div fxFlex="40%" class="blue-color">
     item2
   </div>
</div>
```

or with `space-around` seems to be working. If want something else please provide more specific description.

For `vertical` alignment try to fix somehow the height of the parent element so you can see the children  elements to occupy the empty space accordingly

```
<div fxLayout="column" style='height: 100px;' fxLayoutAlign="space-around none">
   <div fxFlex="20%"  style="background-color: green;">
     item1
   </div>
   <div fxFlex="20%"  style="background-color: blue;">
     item2
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, What will be the solution if I used column instead of row?

Comment: `style='height: 100px;' ` is a temp fix to see what i am talking about, maybe that framework has a better way to specify the height or add some css class

Comment: Excuse-me? Did you just copy paste my demo and answer?

Comment: not at all :) my answer is the "oldest" and i don't see the same code in this page

Comment: I am talking about the update. Your code is taken from my demo. It would be fine, if some credit is done, but this point? Oh well, I have seen this so many times now

Comment: i upvoted your answer :) hope u are happy now. i honestly didn't see the answer

Comment: it's not rocket science so i guess many people can reply with the same or similar answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to see the changes results:

```
<div fxLayout="row" >
   <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex='100%' fxLayoutAlign="space-around none">
      <div fxFlex="40%"  class="green-color">
         item1
      </div>
   <div fxFlex="40%"  class="blue-color">
        item2
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems like the fxFlex="" is representing the cross axes , I thought it represented the main axes.
 but why should I wrap fxLayout="column"  with fxLayout="row"?

Comment: you dont have to wrap it with a row, i just added it to make you see a clear example of that

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work, here is the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7aewww?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: You have to define the column height, I wrapped it in a row instead